# How to disable all mouse events except click?

Tags: javascript, css, click, mouse, pointer-events

I want to disable all mouse events except click, I have this:

```
.info {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: rgba(26, 188, 156, 0.9);
}
```

but pointer-events: none; disables all events.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pointer-events attribute only has three properties:

- none,
- auto,
- inherit

So if you attach

```
    pointer-events: none;
```

to an element all events will be disabled.

```
    pointer-events: auto;
```

however restores all default functionality and is good for if an element's parent has pointer-events: none.

A workaround that I think you'd find useful (aside from some JavaScript manipulation), is to wrap your objects in a parent container and add

```
    pointer-events: none;
```

to that parent container and use:

```
    pointer-events: auto;
```

on .info and add .info to the child elements of the container.

It won't accomplish exactly what you're looking for but it will replicate that click only illusion.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to first make all instances of any one elements as :

```
 pointer-event:none
```

For example here I am making all `img` tags as `pointer-event:none` in css files:

```
img{
        pointer-event:none
     }
```

then you have to enclose your clickable element( for e.g `img` ) inside another tag(like `div, span` )

For example:

```
<div class="enclosing-img-class" click="sampleEvent()">
  <img src="sample.png" alt="No Image available">
</div>
```